# import data from webpage with Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, urlfetch

I just have a a short question:

Current Scenario:
I'd like to "import" data from a webpage. Manually, I'd go to the website, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> (copies everything on that webpage) and than paste the data into `A1` of the current spreadsheet.

Question: Is it possible to implement the part "go to webpage and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>" with google app script? And if so: how?

All help is appreciated and thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/) is some what the equivalent.

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670339/import-data-from-webpage-with-google-app-script';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var text = response.getContentText();
  Logger.log(text);
  // Figure out how to parse the text 
  // Write to the ss
}
```

Comment: Hey Bryan! Thanks for your suggestion. But UrlFetchApp gives only the HTML-Script as output. I need the "plain text" as the user sees it. Any further idea?